# removeSparseTerms() returns a TermDocumentMatrix with empty "Terms" column

Tags: r, tm

I have a term-document matrix generated by DocumentTermMatrix() command from tm package. The input data is a big text file with some Twitter entries. It was being read by `x = read.delim("medium_twi.txt", stringsAsFactors=F, header=F, quote = "")` command, then cleaned\stemmed and finally converted into a term-document matrix. All works like a charm up to now.

Now that's where the problem begins. The inspect command says that the majority of entries are sparse and there are 684012 non-sparse:

```
> inspect(adtm)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 100000, terms: 69456)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 684012/6944915988
Sparsity           : 100%
```

However, when I try to run (0.1 parameter is arbitrary. I've tried even 0.00000001 to see if the problem is with the very low percentage of non-sparse entries, but the result stays the same)

```
adtm2 <- removeSparseTerms(adtm, 0.1)
```

It removes *all* of the terms.

```
> adtm2$dimnames[2]
$Terms
NULL
```

I don't quite understand why is that so, there are definitely some words that are quite frequent:

```
> findFreqTerms(adtm, 4000)
[1] "get"  "good" "just" "like" "love" "will"
```

Please tell me where and what I did wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the inspect says sparsity is 100%, so if you remove sparse terms, perhaps 100% of them are removed.  Did you remove stopwords?  Second, I used the example from the tm package and tdm$dimnames[1] gives terms, not [2].  Just wondering whether your call is correct on adtm2$dimnames[2]

Comment: Thanks! I think it shows 100% because 684012/6944915988 gives a very small fraction and it rounds to 0. Hence, 100-0 = 100. I've worked around now, using additional parameter at term-document-matrix constructor: `adtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(a, control = list(bounds = list(local = c(2,Inf))))`

And the difference between comes, I think, in difference document-term or term-document matrix. The latter has terms first, the former has documents.